# In B-spline, why is the number of knot spans equal to the number curve segments?

Tags: geometry, spline

I will show one example to explain my questions.

Let's say we have 11 control points, degree 3  and 15
knots with first four and last four knots clamped. The number of knot spans is equal to 8.
The number curve segments are also equal to 8 (see figure). Why?
[image]

Comment: A curve segment is defined over each knot span. Therefore, their numbers will always be the same.

Comment: @fang I see. So based on your answer, when the parameter value goes through one knot span. Let's say it is $$u \in  [u_0,u_1]$$. When u at u_0, its corresponding point is at the one side of the curve segment. When u at u_1, its corresponding point is at another side of the curve segment. Am I right?

Comment: @OP: yes. you are correct.